# Como implemento arduino en un juego de p5.js medinate comunicacion serial?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, arduino, socket

#dentro de esta funcion encontramos enteredbasket = true y necesito usar el estado de esta variable para enviarla mediante socket.io al servidor

```
    if (!this.enteredBasket && this.ballFalling) {
      const middleX = (minX + maxX) / 2;

      if (
        this.ball.pos.x >= middleX - this.ballSize / 2 &&
        this.ball.pos.x <= middleX + this.ballSize / 2 &&
        this.ball.pos.y + this.ballSize / 2 >= minY &&
        this.ball.pos.y - this.ballSize / 2 <= maxY
      ) {
        this.enteredBasket = true;
        this.score++;
        
      //  podrías enviar un mensaje al servidor indicando que el balón ha entrado a la canasta
      io.emit('enteredBasket',this.enteredBasket);
      }
    }
  }
```

Este es el servidor

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import { SerialPort } from 'serialport';
import { ReadlineParser } from 'serialport';

const protocolConfiguration = {
  path: 'COM3',
  baudRate: 9600
};

const puertoSerie = new SerialPort(protocolConfiguration);
const parser = puertoSerie.pipe(new ReadlineParser());

// Puerto de la aplicación
const PORT = 5500;

parser.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('Datos del Arduino:', data);
});

const expressApp = express();
expressApp.use(cors());

// URL del mupi y el control
const httpServer = expressApp.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.table({
    'Controller:': 'http://localhost:5500/controller',
    'Game:': 'http://localhost:5500/game',
  });
});

expressApp.use('/game', express.static('public-mupi'));
expressApp.use('/controller', express.static('public-control'));
expressApp.use(express.json());

// Comportamiento del servidor
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  path: '/real-time',
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});

// Variable que indica si el usuario ha ingresado a la canasta

// En tu código donde detectas que el usuario ha ingresado a la canasta, por ejemplo, dentro de la función que maneja el evento 'ballLaunched'
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Usuario conectado');

  // Caída del balón y reseteo en el celular
  socket.on('ballDropped', () => {
    io.emit('ballDropped');
  });

  // Evento para enviar el estado inicial de la variable enteredBasket al cliente
  socket.emit('initialEnteredBasketState', game.enteredBasket);

  // Evento para recibir actualizaciones de la variable enteredBasket desde el cliente
  socket.on('updateEnteredBasket', (data) => {
    game.enteredBasket = data;
    io.emit('updateEnteredBasket', game.enteredBasket);
  });
  const message = this.enteredBasket ? '1' : '0';
  puertoSerie.write(message, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error al escribir en el puerto serial:', err);
   }});
   

  });
```

En el codigo del servidor podemos encontrar como obtengo la informacion de la data que vienen desde el juego por lo que traemos la data y genero una funcion que por cada estado sea un numero y nos diga qe depende el numero prenda los leds pero no funciona.

```
int ledPin = 7;  // Puerto al que está conectado el LED

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char receivedChar = Serial.read();
    if (receivedChar == '1') {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);  // Enciende el LED
    } else if (receivedChar == '0') {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);  // Apaga el LED
    }
  }
}
```

Y finalmente tenemos el código de Arduino estoy perdido en la utilización del estado de la variable para poder prinder el led cuando enteredbasket es true y adicionalmente enteredbasket siempre es false hasta que cambia dentro de la funcion